# Error when importing react-native community picker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm new to react-native, since I'm using Expo and I had to install react-native community picker, I used the following command to install:

```
npm install @react-native-community/picker --save
```

After that I import it like this:

```
import {Picker} from '@react-native-community/picker';
```

But I get the following error:

```
While trying to resolve module `@react-native-community/picker` from file `C:\xampp\htdocs\secondtry\screens\HomeScreen3.js`, the package `C:\xampp\htdocs\secondtry\node_modules\@react-native-community\picker\package.json` was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved (`C:\xampp\htdocs\secondtry\node_modules\@react-native-community\picker\js\index.js`. Indeed, none of these files exist:
```

Comment: What version of React Native are you using?

Comment: "react-native": "~0.62.2",

Comment: And what expo version?

Comment: "expo": "~38.0.8",

Answer (score 4):

You need to use expo command for installing:

```
expo install @react-native-community/picker
```

[Here is doc](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v38.0.0/sdk/picker/)

Answer (score 3):

The Author renamed the library to `@react-native-picker/picker`. Please try to use it.

For details see [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-community/picker) link.